# The value of the new custom field is not displayed in the correct place. Contacts template. Odoo 12

Tags: field, odoo, odoo-12

I am only starting to figure out in developing and now I have a problem with adding the custom field to the existing Contacts template in Odoo12. More precisely, the field added, and the value of this field appears not in the place where it is necessary.

I need to add a new field after the address fields on the main page of the contact. I add this field, but the value of this field does not appear on the MAIN page - it appears only in Invoice address and Shipping address pages

```
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class NewContact(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    new_field = fields.Char("new field:")

_____.xml
    <record id="new_field_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.inherited.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='vat']" position="before">
                <field name="new_field"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

value['new_field'] = "test value text"
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be customizations or inheritance happened to the partner form view. Hence there is a chance of location change for vat field. So if you need the field below address, try giving the below xml code:

```
`<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_address_format')]" position="after">
    <field name="new_field"/>
</xpath>`
```

Comment: can you be more specific about your answer? what was wrong etc

Comment: There may be customizations or inheritance happened to the partner form view. Hence there is a chance of location change for vat field. So if you need the field below address, we may give as above.

Comment: It would be great if you write it on your answer!